# How to find greatest numeric value in Array of string in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of strings

```
NSArray *myNumbers = @[@"0.0454", @"-1.3534", @"0.345",
                             @"65", @"-0.345", @"1.35"];
```

How can I find the greatest numeric value (65) from this array of string?

Is there any default method or workaround for this?

Comment: no default method, i think. u need to code it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort it while converting to float, then get the first or last value depends on your sort

```
NSString *max = [myNumbers sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        float first = [(NSString*)a floatValue];
        float second = [(NSString*)b floatValue];
        if (first > second)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (first < second)
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }][0];
```

or

```
NSString *max = [[myNumbers sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        return [(NSString *)a compare:(NSString *)b options:NSNumericSearch];
    }] lastObject];
```

Comment: That would work, but sorting is a fairly expensive operation, and overkill if all you need is the largest item. It would be faster to simply loop through the list, saving a pointer to the largest item as you go. After one pass you'd have the largest (Which is O(n) performance, versus O(n log n) at best for a sort. I believe Apple's sort routines usually use QuickSort, which has O(n log n) performance at best, and O(n^2) in the worst case.)

Comment: I agree with Duncan, this is way too overkill.